# Selecting/Moving all messages in Inbox on Yahoo! Mail

Tags: yahoo-mail

I am looking for an **efficient** way to move all of my messages (more than 50.000) in Inbox to another folder in Yahoo! Mail.

When I try in new version to *Select All*, only visible messages are selected, ie. if I then scroll down, new loaded messages are not selected, so I would have to scroll down for hours to load "manually" all messages.

Hitting the <kbd>End</kbd> key to go rapidly to the last row is not working, and neither is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>.

Trying on older versions is even slower.

Is there any other way?

**UPDATE**: Yahoo Customer Care answered by email that for the moment the only way to achieve this is scrolling down until the last row and then *Select All* !

It is surprising for me. A big one like Yahoo! Mail with such a limitation...

Any other idea or workaround? Maybe managing those messages as if they were in a database, from other webapp. I don't know if that is possible...

Comment: I would like to get this question moved to Superuser. Maybe it will be answered there.

Comment: Posts older than 60 days cannot be migrated.  They would likely reject it as being off-topic at this point anyway.

Comment: @jonsca I understand the 60 days limit (I didn't realise). But, do you mean that Wepapps is the only right stackexchange site for this question?

Comment: Yes, since Yahoo Mail is considered to be a web application, we are the only place for questions like this on SE.  The folks on SU would likely migrate it here if you asked a new question there.  I wish I had better news, but that's just the way it is.

Comment: If Yahoo allows IMAP access, using an external mail client may be a possibility.

Comment: @jonsca That sounds good... I never did use that protocol. I will check it out... Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just managed to do this in a very round-about way on a fluke. Was so happy to have discovered it. Here's what I did:

1. Go to inbox
2. Click on "Unread" in left hand column
3. At the top, you will now see the number of unread emails and an option to "refine" your search. Click on "refine"
4. A box will pop up..here, you will change the search option that says "unread" to "inbox"...you will also change the Dates option to "custom" and enter in as large of a span of dates as you think you have in your email inbox (format yyyy/mm/dd)
5. This should pull up almost all of your emails and allow you to click the little select all box to "move" to transfer them over to another folder as you normally would for a smaller amount.

It may take a long while for it all to transfer and there may be a few hundred left in the inbox at the end which you can just transfer as usual.

Comment: Great! It works!
The trick is that in the results view that you describe, when you select all messages and then you scroll down to load other messages, these are selected as they appear. This means that all messages are really selected, not only those that are visible. ¡Yeah!

Comment: This works using a direct search by date, as well. Open Yahoo! Mail, and in the search field write something like:  after:"2010/01/01" before:"2010/12/31"

Comment: Doesn't work in the new-view. Probably worked in classic view, which is no where to be found now.

Answer (score 2):

Note, this appears to only work in the Classic view. In the newer version, even though emails are auto selected as you scroll, the move function (and other bulk functions) only moves those currently visible. If you switch back to classic, the select All actually has the non-visible ones selected "behind the scenes" and the move function will move them all.  Amazing the hoops you need to jump through to work with bulk email!

Comment: _What_ "only work[s] in the Classic view"? Are you referring to another answer. Note that answers can be sorted different ways; they're seldom shown in chronological order. If you're referring to another answer, please link to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just scroll down continuously and check the select all check box and then move to required folder. All the emails which are visible will be moved. this is simplest way to move all the emails.

Comment: 50000+ emails? scroll down?! Unfortunately I need 125 rep to downvote..